# Multiple contents based in same design modal

Tags: javascript, html, css

```css
.modal {
  display: none;
  /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed;
  /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1;
  /* Sit on top */
  padding-top: 100px;
  /* Location of the box */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /* Full width */
  height: 100%;
  /* Full height */
  overflow: auto;
  /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  /* Black w/ opacity */
  font-size: 14px;
}
/* Modal Content */

.modal-content {
  position: relative;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 80%;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  -webkit-animation-name: animatetop;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
  animation-name: animatetop;
  animation-duration: 0.4s
}
/* Add Animation */

@-webkit-keyframes animatetop {
  from {
    top: -300px;
    opacity: 0
  }
  to {
    top: 0;
    opacity: 1
  }
}
@keyframes animatetop {
  from {
    top: -300px;
    opacity: 0
  }
  to {
    top: 0;
    opacity: 1
  }
}
/* The Close Button */

.close {
  color: white;
  float: right;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: red;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.modal-header {
  padding: 2px 16px;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
.modal-body {
  padding: 2px 16px;
}
.album {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
</head>


<body>

  <div class="album">
    <img src="seventhalbum.jpg" alt="First Album" style="width:300;height300;">
    <p></p>
    <!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
    <button id="myBtn">Californication</button>

    <!-- The Modal -->
    <div id="myModal" class="modal">

      <!-- Modal content -->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <span class="close">X</span>
          <h2>Californication</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>1: Around the World</p>
          <p>2: Parallel Universe</p>
          <p>3: Scar Tissue</p>
          <p>4: Otherside</p>
          <p>5: Get on Top</p>
          <p>6: Californication</p>
          <p>7: Easily</p>
          <p>8: Porcelain</p>
          <p>9: Emit Remmus</p>
          <p>10: I Like Dirt</p>
          <p>11: This Velvet Glove</p>
          <p>12: Savior</p>
          <p>13: Purple Stain</p>
          <p>14: Right on Time</p>
          <p>15: Road Trippin'</p>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
    <p></p>
  </div>
  <div class="album">
    <img src="eigthalbum.jpg" alt="First Album" style="width:300;height300;">
    <p></p>
    <!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
    <button id="myBtn1">By the Way</button>

    <!-- The Modal -->
    <div id="myModal1" class="modal">

      <!-- Modal content -->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <span class="close1">X</span>
          <h2>By the Way</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>1: By the Way</p>
          <p>2: Universally Speaking</p>
          <p>3: This Is the Place</p>
          <p>4: Dosed</p>
          <p>5: Don't Forget Me</p>
          <p>6: The Zephyr Song</p>
          <p>7: Can't Stop</p>
          <p>8: I Could Die for You</p>
          <p>9: Midnight</p>
          <p>10: Through Away Your Television</p>
          <p>11: Cabron</p>
          <p>12: Tear</p>
          <p>13: On Mercury</p>
          <p>14: Minor Thing</p>
          <p>15: Warm Tape</p>
          <p>16: Venice Queen</p>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>


    <script>
      // Get the modal
      var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

       // Get the button that opens the modal
      var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

       // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
      var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

       // When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
      btn.onclick = function() {
        modal.style.display = "block";
      }

       // When the user clicks on <span> (X), close the modal
      span.onclick = function() {
        modal.style.display = "none";
      }

       // When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
      window.onclick = function(event) {
        if (event.target == modal) {
          modal.style.display = "none";
        }
      }
    </script>

    <script>
      // Get the modal
      var modal = document.getElementById('myModal1');

       // Get the button that opens the modal
      var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn1");

       // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
      var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close1")[0];

       // When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
      btn.onclick = function() {
        modal.style.display = "block";
      }

       // When the user clicks on <span> (X), close the modal
      span.onclick = function() {
        modal.style.display = "none";
      }

       // When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
      window.onclick = function(event) {
        if (event.target == modal) {
          modal.style.display = "none";
        }
      }
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Im trying to have my page to where there are Multiple buttons that open up different Modal contents, but using the same script and css design. Im having an issue where it oly opens up  one certain example. (By the Way album only displaying) how can I fix this issue, labeling the divs different did not work, atleast not for me. The two buttons in my snippet show the issue.

Comment: you need an id for each modal and a class for all to style them (id can be used only once, class as much as needed )

Comment: Please minimize your code

Comment: Sorry, this is my first post and my first website I've ever coded so I'll see f i can edit the code

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Can you make a short example that contains only the stuff necessary to demonstrate the problem? I suggest you read stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for learning hoe to that and why it is important. It's pretty difficult to search for a problem if you post too much code. You'll get better answers if you can provide a better example.

Comment: I'm a noob, so how can I edit my code snippet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the `var`'s in the second modal in the javascript that is different from the other.

See fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/DIRTY_SMITH/7oe5kh9L/10/

```
// Get the modal
var modal1 = document.getElementById('myModal1');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn1 = document.getElementById("myBtn1");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span1 = document.getElementsByClassName("close1")[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
btn1.onclick = function() {
    modal1.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (X), close the modal
span1.onclick = function() {
    modal1.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal1) {
        modal1.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a BUNCH!!! Ill remember to do that for the other 8 and it should run smooth. Thank you again!!